# telerik report objectdatasource with dependency ninject

Tags: telerik, report, objectdatasource

In Telerik Report i have set objectdatasource to bind data in MVC4, While loading view is perfect my injection (Ninject), but while method call from objectdatasource, i am getting null reference error.

Please advice me, hot to fix the issue